# ActionScript 2.0 - Matching Traces Don't Actually Match

Tags: actionscript, match, trace

(lord help me for programming in AS2)

i'm itterating thru an array of text field objects and tracing the selected focus field when pressing tab, as well as each object.

i'm trying to equate these object, but while they trace the exact same they are not.

```
m_InputFieldsArray = new Array(m_TitleTextInput, m_CommentsTextArea, m_EmailTextInput);

for (var i:Number = 0; i < m_InputFieldsArray.length; i++)
{
    trace("Get Focus: " + Selection.getFocus());
    trace("Arr Index: " + m_InputFieldsArray[i].textField);

    if (Selection.getFocus() == m_InputFieldsArray[i].textField) 
    {
        trace("Match!");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        trace("NO Match!");
    }
}
```

the output:

```
Get Focus: _level0.m_Window.form.m_TitleTextInput.textField
Arr Index: _level0.m_Window.form.m_TitleTextInput.textField
NO Match!
Get Focus: _level0.m_Window.form.m_TitleTextInput.textField
Arr Index: _level0.m_Window.form.m_CommentsTextArea.textField
NO Match!
Get Focus: _level0.m_Window.form.m_TitleTextInput.textField
Arr Index: _level0.m_Window.form.m_EmailTextInput.textField
NO Match!
```

the first group traces the same, but apparently they do not match.  `Selection.getFocus()` returns a string, while the array index is tracing the text field object.  if i add `toString()` to the text field object it will trace as `[Object object]`

how can i accomplish a match?

Comment: `m_TitleTextInput` and the others Components?

Comment: yes, they are customized Scaleform components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eval()` for the `Selection.getFocus()`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, if you don't want to use eval(), that has a [bad reputation](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22eval%20is%20evil%22%20%2bactionscript), to get the same kind of string representation as Selection.getFocus() returns, you can use `"" + m_InputFieldsArray[i].textField`. It won't return "[Object object]", as `toString()` does.

That is basically what you see in your trace calls, that a string concatenated with the object reference gives the path to the object, rather than .toString() on the object.

I can't test AS2 right now, but I'm pretty sure that is how it works. So you could do something like this:

```
if (Selection.getFocus() == "" + m_InputFieldsArray[i].textField)
```